What is the way to properly pipe output of 'poetry show' command?
I am using python 3.11, poetry version 1.7.1, and on macOS.
I have a dependency group, models.
The output for the following command:
❯ poetry show --top-level --only models
model1             3.7.1 https://github.com/<somerepo>/<somefile>.whl   <description text>
model2            3.7.3 https://github.com/<somerepo>/<somefile>.whl <description text>

But when I try to pipe the output to a text file, it only pipes:
model1
model2

I have tried grep, awk, setting TERM=dumb but it doesn't seem to pipe the full output. Is this because of special characters?
I also tried:
❯ poetry show --top-level --only models | cat -v
model1           
model2  


Some commands adapt their output depending on whether they are connected to a terminal. The Poetry documentation doesn't mention anything about this. The --ansi option doesn't seem relevant for this, though it's probably similarly enabled or disabled depending on whether it's connected to a terminal. I guess ultimately you could do poetry show | xargs poetry show to get all details about every package, and filter it back down to the details you care about. (Not at my computer, and not a Poetry user.)

It seems that poetry changes its output behavior depending on whether it's writing to a terminal (TTY) or being piped to a file (non-TTY). I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 and found that simulating a TTY resolves this issue. I ended up using the following command:
script -q /dev/null -c "poetry show --top-level --only models --no-interaction --no-ansi" > poetry_out.txt

This effectively simulates a TTY while redirecting the output to a file.

if my understanding is correct, you are trying to get the output of a poetry show command into a file.
assuming this, you can use redirection operator  (This guy >)
syntax: poetry show <required options> > <your file name>

required options --> here you will add --top-level --only models

your file name --> to which file you want to pipe into


eg: poetry show --top-level > top-level.txt
i just tried to replicate same in y windows 11using bash

please let us know if you have any questions

That's strange, I don't have the versions and descriptions in my .txt file after doing this. Tried on both bash and zsh.

what is the command you are trying can you share a screenshot?

❯ poetry show --top-level > output.txt
❯ cat output.txt
Output:
camel-converter
coverage
docformatter
Truncated rest, but as can be seen no version or description.

These are basic linux commands. nothing new
poetry show --top-level > output.txt
cat output.txt
there might be some issue with your local configuration i gues
